# Law of Large Numbers Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I'm studying Law of Large Numbers and came across the next question: so, I know that if I have $ X_1 \ldots X_n $ independent random variables with $ X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2),\  \forall i = 1, \ldots n \ $ then

$$ \overline{X_n} = \dfrac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} \sim N(\mu, \dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}) $$

for any given value $n$.

I also know, because of the Law of Large Numbers, that the arithmethic mean of the random variables $\overline{X_n}$ converges to the expected value when $n \rightarrow \infty$ i.e.

$$\overline{X_n} = \dfrac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} \rightarrow \mu \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ \ \ \ \ \ n \rightarrow \infty $$

But I'm wondering if the first statement is a contradiction to the Law of Large Numbers.

Edit: I was wondering that if, in the first statement, when $n \rightarrow \infty$ we can assume that the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{X_n} \sim N(\mu, 0) $? That would mean that our distribution has no standard deviation so, all the values in the random variables will be $\mu$, but what's causing me conflict is that how can we say that the arithmetic mean of random variables converges to a distribution and because of the Law of Large Numbers converges, also, to a number.

Comment: Could you explain more about how you believe the decreasing standard error in the mean (with increasing n) contradicts the LLN?

Comment: Hint: What happens to the variance of $\overline{X}_n$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Sure, please let me edit the question.

Comment: No it is not a contradiction. You see, the variance of $\overline{X_n}$ is going to zero, as it should be, cause then we have $\overline{X_n} \rightarrow \mu$ in distribution in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,0)$ with variance zero does not exists in that way. With the right understanding what "$\mathcal{N}(\mu,0)$" has to be, yes, you can assume $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{X_n} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,0)$.
So what is $\mathcal{N}(\mu,0)$?

We better understand this as limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. Roughly speaking the gaussian density function concentrates all mass at point $\mu$. With a bit more theory we can determine

$\mathcal{N}(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}) \rightarrow \delta_\mu$

where $\delta_\mu$ is the Dirac-Distribution of $\mu$, i.e. $\delta_\mu ([a,b]) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \mu \in [a,b] \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

This means nothing else that, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{X_n} \sim  \delta_\mu$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{X_n} = \mu$ almost surely (this is the same result of LLN)